# Error iterando sobre std::list

Tags: c++

Tengo un grafo con nodos. Los nodos están diseñados de forma que tienen un puntero al padre, y una lista con los punteros a los hijos, además de un valor. Están en la clase ItemTree.

**ItemTree.h**

```
#ifndef ITEMTREE_H
#define ITEMTREE_H

#include <list>
#include <string>


class ItemTree
{
    public:
        ItemTree();
        ItemTree(std::string valor, ItemTree* padre=nullptr);
        virtual ~ItemTree();
        ItemTree* Padre();
        void AnadirPadre(ItemTree* padre);
        void AnadirHijo(ItemTree* hijo);
        bool HayHijos();
        std::list<ItemTree*> Hijos();
        std::string Valor();

    protected:

    private:
        std::string m_valor;
        ItemTree* m_parentItem;
        std::list<ItemTree*> m_hijos;
};

#endif // ITEMTREE_H
```

**ItemTree.cpp**

```
#include "ItemTree.h"

ItemTree::ItemTree():m_parentItem(nullptr)
{
    //ctor
}

ItemTree::ItemTree(std::string valor, ItemTree* padre):m_valor(valor),m_parentItem(padre)
{
    if (padre)
    {
        padre->AnadirHijo(this);
    }
}

ItemTree::~ItemTree()
{
    //dtor
}

ItemTree* ItemTree::Padre()
{
    return m_parentItem;
}

void ItemTree::AnadirPadre(ItemTree* padre)
{
    m_parentItem=padre;
}

void ItemTree::AnadirHijo(ItemTree* hijo)
{
    m_hijos.push_back(hijo);
    hijo->m_parentItem = this;
}

bool ItemTree::HayHijos()
{
    return !m_hijos.empty();
}

std::list<ItemTree*> ItemTree::Hijos()
{
    return m_hijos;
}

std::string ItemTree::Valor()
{
    return m_valor;
}
```

Estos ItemTree se usan en una clase Grafo:

**GrafoArbol.h**

```
#ifndef GRAFOARBOL_H
#define GRAFOARBOL_H

#include "ItemTree.h"


class GrafoArbol
{
    public:
        GrafoArbol();
        virtual ~GrafoArbol();
        void AnadirHijo (ItemTree* padre, ItemTree* hijo);
        void RecorrerArbol(ItemTree* nodo);
        ItemTree* Raiz();

    protected:

    private:
        ItemTree* m_raiz;
};

#endif // GRAFOARBOL_H
```

.**GrafoArbol.cpp**

```
#include "GrafoArbol.h"
#include <iostream>

GrafoArbol::GrafoArbol()
{
    m_raiz = new ItemTree("RAIZ");
}

GrafoArbol::~GrafoArbol()
{
    //dtor
}

void GrafoArbol::AnadirHijo (ItemTree* padre, ItemTree* hijo)
{
    padre->AnadirHijo(hijo);
}

ItemTree* GrafoArbol::Raiz()
{
    return m_raiz;
}

void GrafoArbol::RecorrerArbol(ItemTree* nodo)
{
    std::cout<<"Nodo: "<<nodo->Valor()<<std::endl;
    if (nodo->HayHijos())
    {
        auto it = nodo->Hijos().begin();
        for (size_t i=0;i<nodo->Hijos().size();i++)
        {
            RecorrerArbol(*it);
            ++it;
        }
        std::cout<<nodo->Valor()<<" - ";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout<<nodo->Valor()<<" - ";
    }
}
```

Y por último lo uso así

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "GrafoArbol.h"

int main()
{
    GrafoArbol arbol;
    ItemTree* A1 = new ItemTree("A1",arbol.Raiz());
    ItemTree* A2 = new ItemTree("A2",arbol.Raiz());
    ItemTree* A3 = new ItemTree("A3",arbol.Raiz());     

    cout<<arbol.Raiz()->Hijos().size()<<endl;
    cout<<arbol.Raiz()->Hijos().front()->Valor()<<" - "<<arbol.Raiz()->Hijos().back()->Valor()<<endl;
    //esta forma de iterar da error
    /*for (auto it = arbol.Raiz()->Hijos().begin();it != arbol.Raiz()->Hijos().end();++it)
    {
        cout<<(*it)->Valor()<<endl;
    }*/
    //esta forma de iterar funciona
    for (auto elem : arbol.Raiz()->Hijos())
    {
        cout<<elem->Valor()<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Tal como está ahora, itera correctamente sobre la lista de hijos del nodo raiz y me muestra los tres valores. Pero si lo hago de la forma que está comentada (for auto it=....) el programa me da error, me muestra los dos primeros valores y sale con error.

Comment: ¿Cuál error obtienes?

Comment: Me sabe mal tener que decirle esto a un usuario de mas de 6 años y un montón de preguntas y respuestas: deberías revisar [¿ Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta ?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), así como lo que es un [mcve]. 4 bloques de código distintos (en lugar de uno que se pueda copiar/pegar); un montón de código irrelevante; y ni siquiera está claro el error.

Comment: @Mateo, error de segmentación

Comment: @Trauma soy consciente de que hay mucho código, pero intuía que el error no estaba en la iteración en sí, sino en la propia clase donde se iteraba. Por eso la puse entera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu error es devolver la lista de hijos por copia:

```
class ItemTree
{
        …

        std::list<ItemTree*> Hijos();

        …
};
```

Cuando intentas iterar:

```
for (auto it = arbol.Raiz()->Hijos().begin();it != arbol.Raiz()->Hijos().end();++it)
{
    cout<<(*it)->Valor()<<endl;
}
```

Sucede esto:

1. Devuelves una copia de la lista de hijos de `arbol`.
2. De la copia, obtienes el iterador de inicio.
3. Al acabar la sentencia, se destruye la copia.

   - El iterador de inicio queda apuntando a una lista borrada.
4. En la primera vuelta del bucle, devuelves otra copia de la lista de hijos de `arbol`.
5. De la copia, obtienes el iterador de final.
6. Se destruye la copia, quedando el iterador de final apuntando al final de una lista que no existe.
7. Lo comparas con el iterador de inicio que además de ser de una lista diferente, es de una lista que no existe.
8. Fallo.

Te aconsejo que devuelvas los iteradores directamente:

```
class ItemTree
{
        …

        auto begin() { return m_hijos.begin(); }
        auto end() { return m_hijos.begin(); }
        auto begin() const { return m_hijos.cbegin(); }
        auto end() const { return m_hijos.cend(); }

        …
};
```

Y podrás iterar con un `for` de rango:

```
for (auto item : *arbol.Raiz())
{
    cout << item->Valor() << endl;
}
```

###### **Editado**.

> ¿No podría hacer que la función devolviera la lista por referencia `std::list<ItemTree*>& Hijos();`.

Claro que puedes, pero eso rompería los principios del [encapsulamiento](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulamiento_(inform%C3%A1tica)) al dar acceso a un miembro privado de tu clase. Podrías argumentar que devolver iteradores de lectura/escritura sucede lo mismo y tendrías razón parcialmente:

```
auto begin() { return m_hijos.begin(); }
auto end() { return m_hijos.begin(); }
```

Si devuelves los iteradores de lectura/escritura tendrás la capacidad de modificar los elementos de la lista, pero no podrás modificar la lista en si (borrar elementos, añadir elementos, vaciar o mover la lista).

> Sigo sin entender por qué de la forma incorrecta -por valor- puedo iterar con un `for` de rango y no con iterador al estilo más "clásico".

Porque un `for` de rango es un [azúcar sintáctico](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Az%C3%BAcar_sint%C3%A1ctico) de un código más complejo que puede consultarse en [el estándar de C++](https://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/n4950.pdf):

> #### 8.6.5 El bucle `for` de rango
>
> El bucle `for` de rango
>
> `for (` *declaración<sub>opt</sub>* *declaración-del-bucle* `:` *inicializador-del-bucle* `)` *declaración*
>
> Es equivalente a:
>
> `{`
>
> *declaración<sub>opt</sub>*
>
> `auto &&rango =` *inicializador-del-bucle* `;`
>
> `auto begin =` *expresión-begin* `;`
>
> `auto end =` *expresión-end* `;`
>
> `for ( ; begin != end ; ++begin ) {`
>
> *declaración-del-bucle* `= * begin ;`
>
> *declaración*
>
> `}`
>
> `}`

Si te fijas, se está guardando el temporal en una referencia del lado derecho (`auto &&rango =` *inicializador-del-bucle* `;`) lo cuál alarga la vida del temporal lo suficiente como para poder iterar el objeto.

Comment: Impecable la explicación. Solo dos preguntas: 1.- No podría hacer que la función devolviera la lista por referencia `std::list<ItemTree*>& Hijos();` y 2.- Sigo sin entender por qué de la forma incorrecta -por valor- puedo iterar con un for de rango y no con iterador al estilo más "clásico".

Comment: 1) Claro que puedes, pero no es considerado buena práctica. 2) Porque el `for` de rango es más de lo que parece a simple vista. He editado mi respuesta.